# Multi-file upload field not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, multifile-uploader

I am running a wordpress/woocommerce site and I just installed Gravity Forms. After creating a form with a multi-file upload section, it won't seem to work. The select button does nothing and when you try to drag over image files, they just open in the browser.

I did find a post regarding the issue, but when I followed the simple instructions on how to remedy the problem...it still did nothing. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the page with the multi-upload form:
http://www.ashlynnpress.com/product/letterhead/
(Disregard the other upload buttons)

The supposed solution is to simply "activate" scripts on the page by inserting the following line of code in the header. But again, when I tried that it did nothing.

```
<?php
    gravity_form_enqueue_scripts(2, true);
?>
```

The "2" refers to the form id and the "true" refers to the AJAX.